# Carousel with preview of the next and previous image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to re-learn webprogramming since it's been long since then that I have made one (I actually don't like web programming but a need might come anytime soon)

Anyhow what my problem is that, I'm trying to replicate this one https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/RKavve/
I've been aple to replicate until the display of the image but the functions to slide and the arrows it self is not working and cannot be seen.

Here's my code:
HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets\css\bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets\css\mycss1.css">

    </head>
    <body>


<div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide multi-item-carousel" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <div class="item__third">
        <img src="assets\img\lightblue.png" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="item__third">
        <img src="assets\img\red.png" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="item__third">
        <img src="assets\img\orange.png" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#carousel-1" class="left carousel-control" role="button" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
  <a href="#carousel-1" class="right carousel-control" role="button" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
</div>
        <script src="assets\js\bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
        <script src="assets\js\carouselengine1.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

The css:

```
.multi-item-carousel {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.multi-item-carousel img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.multi-item-carousel .carousel-control.left, 
.multi-item-carousel .carousel-control.right {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    width: 25%;
}
.multi-item-carousel .carousel-inner {
  width: 150%;
  left: -25%;
}
.carousel-inner > .item.next, 
.carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(33%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(33%, 0, 0);
}
.carousel-inner > .item.prev, 
.carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-33%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-33%, 0, 0);
}
.item__third {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33333333%;
}
```

and finally the JS.

```
$(".multi-item-carousel .item").each(function() {
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (!next.length) next = $(this).siblings(":first");
  next
    .children(":first-child")
    .clone()
    .appendTo($(this));
});
$(".multi-item-carousel .item").each(function() {
  var prev = $(this).prev();
  if (!prev.length) prev = $(this).siblings(":last");
  prev
    .children(":nth-last-child(2)")
    .clone()
    .prependTo($(this));
});
```

I'm not new to programming but is at web.
Lastly can someone explain to me what is the use of $(".xxxx .xxx").each()

Also, I'm getting $ not defined error

Comment: `$(".multi-item-carousel .item").each(function() {...` The first set of parens is the selector: *"Get **all** elements that have the class `.item` and is a descendant of  an element with the class `..multi-item-carousel`"* then the `.each()` method takes that jQuery collection of `element.item`s and runs a function on *each* of them.

Comment: Oh i see if I were to word it it would be for each .item in .multi-item-carousel run function() but i read somewhere that $() is a substitute of document.getelementbyid but was not mentioned that it can be used to call classes, is this true?

Comment: which version of bootstrap you use ?

Comment: @HTMLCSSHuppTechnologies the downloaded one from getbootstrap.com

Comment: if you use bootstrap4 then your  example "https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/RKavve/" not working, you need to  add "bootstrap 3.3.7" for use this example.

Comment: @HTMLCSSHuppTechnologies hmm okay, I thought by having 4 it actually compiles all of the bootstrap from 1 to 3. By the way I'm getting this error in console (chrome)  Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at carouselengine1.js:4

Answer (score 1):

The use of `$(".xxxx .xxx").each()` is to add the previous and next items in the list as child items of an item. Those child items are what are used to show the previews.

Answer (score -1):

Hello Try below slider plugins code for bootstrap may be this will solve your issue.

https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/responsive-thumb-preview-in-carousel-indicators

Comment: This might help him but your answer does only consist of a link to an external resource. This is on SO no allowed answer. The external resource could go offline and will not help anyone anymore. Please avoid such answer since they will get downvoted.